# Подключение sfml библиотеки

Tags: c++, visual-studio, sfml

Пытаюсь подключить `sfml` библиотеку к своему `VC++` проекту. Использую `VS15`, `Release` мод без использования `dll`. Делаю всё в соответствии с этой официальной инструкцией http://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.4/start-vc.php для `static` линковки. Если в "дополнительных зависимостях" указываю `sfml-graphics-s.lib;sfml-window-s.lib;sfml-system-s.lib;opengl32.lib;freetype.lib;jpeg.lib;winmm.lib;gdi32.lib;` + унаследованные значения, то получаю

> Ошибка    LNK1181 не удается открыть входной файл "sfml-graphics-s.lib"

Если залезть в папку `lib` и написать в зависимостях непосредственно имена библиотек `libsfml-graphics-s.a` и т.д., то эта ошибка пропадает и появляются ошибки неразрешённых внешних символов.

Файл `main.cpp` из туториала

```
#include "stdafx.h" // там есть #include <SFML\Graphics.hpp>

int main()
{
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(200, 200), "SFML works!");
    sf::CircleShape shape(100.f);
    shape.setFillColor(sf::Color::Green);

    while (window.isOpen()) {
        sf::Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event)) {
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                window.close();
        }

        window.clear();
        window.draw(shape);
        window.display();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Как это можно исправить?

Comment: `SFML_STATIC` добавил, если что

Comment: libsfml-graphics-s.a - есть у меня подозрение что *.a студией не поддерживаются.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов возможно, но при каноничном варианте из туториала, т.е. `sfml-graphics-s.lib` файл не открывается

Comment: А этот "sfml-graphics-s.lib" вообще есть на диске-то?

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов файла с таким именем в библиотеке нет, есть `libsfml-graphics-s.a`

Comment: lib, который наверное понимается студией нет, зато есть .a, который студией вероятно не понимается. Вот и проблема.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов думаю, составители библиотеки добавили все нужные файлы, а в студии специальный синтаксис для добавления зависимостей

Comment: @Студия умеет *.lib, у вас их нет, понимаете?

Comment: `.a` — это для Linux'а, наверное. Или может для MinGW. Попробуйте убедиться, что вы скачали бинарники именно для Visual Studio.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов и что тогда делать?

Comment: По вашей ссылке: «The next step is to link your application to the SFML libraries (**.lib files**)».

Comment: Качать версию для вашей VS, для начала. Версия для VC14 не содержит *.a вовсе.

Comment: @VladD теоретически это возможно, т.к. у меня браузер определяет линукс, но я качал с ссылки непосредственно для windows, вот http://www.sfml-dev.org/download/sfml/2.4.0/, в разделе винды выбрал c++14, мб меня перенаправило. не могли бы вы скачать и проверить содержимое папки lib?

Comment: Уже проверено. VC14 не содержит *.a вовсе.

Comment: @VladD черт! действительно перенаправило, скачал, там .lib файлы!!! 5 часов бился с разными параметрами компоновщика

Comment: всем спасибо, извините за глупый вопрос

Comment: Ну вот и хорошо, что проблема решилась.

Answer (score 1):

Здравствуйте, стоит заметить, что необходимо скачивать только ту версию sfml, которая подходит к Вашей Visual Studio и разрядности. Ещё я пользовался давненько этой инструкцией http://kychka-pc.ru/sfml/urok-1-podklyuchenie-biblioteki-k-srede-razrabotki-visual-studio-2013.html, помогло и работало, правда там рассказано на примере VS 2013 и  работало у меня все в debug(просто relese не пробовал). Да, согласно этому источнику в определении препроцессора использовался SFML_DYNAMIC и также ряд dll библиотек, который автор любезно предоставил.